# How to notify currently app installed users from publisher account

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded an android app in google play successfully as a free application, after that I lost my licence key. Now I have an updated apk but I'm not able to upload it on google play because I lack the key. So at least I want to notify users from the publishers page that a new version is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, There is no way to notify to the users until if you have anything related to send the push notification to your last app which is in the Google Play.

Comment: Suppose if i unpublished my app then my users will get notification?

Comment: No, they won't get any notification.

Comment: Thank you @Williams so if i lost key then i lost permissions to do any thing .Hmmmm :-( i am loosing my 500+ downloads ,If possible save me.

Comment: Don't you have keystore file which you used to sign the app when you uploaded the app first time?

Comment: No That is main problem ,thats why i am looking for alternatives .If i have keystore then happily i will update my app in google play with new apk but i lost it

Comment: Then no way to go for it.